# Why isn't my ReactJs App not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Iam writing a cookbook app.
The recipes of the cookbook are stored in yaml files and these are being stored in a static way. When I load up the site, it will automatically reach out to an index.json file in which all recipes are indexed and load them one after one and add them to an array. This array is then given to the setRecipe method where it should update the dom accordingly.
This doesn't happen.
I already tried to console.log a little and when doing this I get logged the expected data but as soon as I refresh the page this isn't case anymore. The request for the yaml files are being done. Why does that happen?

Full Sourcecode

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import jsyaml from 'js-yaml'
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const basePath = '/k0chbuch'
const recipeStore = basePath + '/recipe-store'
const index = recipeStore + '/index.json'

const RecipeList = () => {
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAllRecipes();
    }, []);
    const fetchAllRecipes = () => {
        fetch(index)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(recipeIndex => {
                let store = []
                recipeIndex.forEach(element => {
                    fetch(recipeStore + '/' + element + '.yaml')
                        .then(res => res.blob())
                        .then(blob => blob.text())
                        .then(text => jsyaml.load(text))
                        .then(recipeObject => {
                            store.push(recipeObject)
                        })
                    
                })
                return store
            })
            .then((all) => setRecipes(all));
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Rezepte:</h1>
            <ListGroup>
                {recipes.map((r)=>(<ListGroupItem>{r.Titel}</ListGroupItem>))}
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    );
};
export default RecipeList;
```

Simple Yaml example:

```yaml
---
Titel: Hackbraten
Autor: d3v3lop3r
Komplexitaet: 1 
Portionen: 4
Zutaten:
  - 1000g Hack
  - 150g Zwiebeln
  - Gewürze nach Wahl
Zubereitung: |
  Zuerst wird das Hack gewürzt, dann die Zwiebeln braten und dem Hack zugeben. Kräftig kneten, dann bei 200°C eine Stunde backen.

Kommentar: Schmeckt am besten mit Kartoffeln!
```

Comment: It did not. I can read the parsed objects via console.log

Comment: Your issue is with the second `.then()` statement: the foreach loop does not wait for the `store` variable to be populated, i.e. you are returning an empty `store` array since the array is being populated asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes with populating the `store` array in your second `.then()`: when using `Array.prototype.forEach`, remember that `return` doesn't really do anything. You are not awaiting for the blob to be parsed before resolving the promise. In fact, this section of the daisy chained promises resolves **immediately**:

```
.then(recipeIndex => {
    let store = [];
    recipeIndex.forEach(element => {
        fetch(...);
    });

    // `store` is returned immediately without waiting for forEach!
    return store;
})
```

Instead, I would suggest using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array of promises based off `recipeIndex`. Then return [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which ensures that all promises are resolved:

```
fetch(index)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(recipeIndex => {
        const promises = recipeIndex.map((element) => {
            return fetch(recipeStore + '/' + element + '.yaml')
                .then(res => res.blob())
                .then(blob => blob.text())
                .then(text => jsyaml.load(text));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then((all) => setRecipes(all));
```

---

### What about using `for` loop? (You can, but not recommended)

An alternative is to use a `for` loop, which you can then use async/await. However I would typically not suggest this for two reasons:

1. `for` loop + `await` means that each requests are dispatched after each other and **not in parallel**, which increases latency. The `Array.prototype.map` solution above dispatches fetch requests at the same time.
2. some linters out there discourage nesting of async callbacks inside `.then()`

However if you want to give it a try, a `for` loop is totally doable:

```
fetch(index)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(async (recipeIndex) => {
        const recipes = [];
        for (const element of recipeIndex) {
            const recipe = await fetch(recipeStore + '/' + element + '.yaml')
                .then(res => res.blob())
                .then(blob => blob.text())
                .then(text => jsyaml.load(text));
            recipes.push(recipe);
        }
    })
    .then((all) => setRecipes(all));
```

Comment: This is not working, as the map seems not to be executed. const promises = recipeIndex.map(() => {console.log("Hello") ... is not appearing in the console.

Comment: Hello is now being displayed.

Comment: But the recipes array is empty

Comment: @Marvin My bad: forgot to pass in `element` as an argument in the callback for `Array.prototype.map`. See updated answer.

Comment: There was a missing parameter in the map function. Now it is working as expected :)

Comment: @Marvin Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs based on the dependency array that is passed as the second argument of the `useEffect` hook.

Try this,

```js
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!recipes && recipes.length == 0){
    fetchAllRecipes();
  }
}, [recipes])
```

This will cause your `useEffect` hook to call as soon as the `recipes` state changes but will only cause the `fetchRecipes()` function to call if the `recipes` state is `null` or the length of the array is 0

Comment: If you do this it may cause an infinite loop, if the data returned by the server changes from time to time (i.e. `fetchAllRecipes()` changes the value of `recipes`, which then triggers a fetch, so on and so forth). Using `recipes` in the dependency array is not needed.

Comment: It won't go into an infinite loop for sure. I have added the if condition specifically for this reason. Also, the reason might be as simple as putting the ```fetchAllRecipes``` function inside the ```useEffect``` callback.

Comment: It will. `!recipes && recipes.length` does not guarantee `recipes` has not mutated.

Comment: Also, the reason might be as simple as putting the ```fetchAllRecipes``` function inside the ```useEffect``` callback.

Comment: Nope. You're missing the point. The issue is due to returning an empty `store` due to the async nature of parsing the text blob.

Comment: For a very short period this displayed the expected result. But as soon as I refresh the page everything is gone

Comment: The answer of Terry fixed it. Thank you helping :)

Comment: I just realized that @Terry